# Как правильно использовать GridSearchCV в sklearn?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

**Имею:** код, строящий GridSearchCV с KNN классификатором.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = [{'weights': ["uniform", "distance"], 'n_neighbors': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}]

KNN_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(KNN_clf, param_grid, cv=5, verbose=3)
grid_search.fit(train_data_values, train_data_labels)
```

**Проблема:** не могу понять, я могу использовать `grid_search` после обучения как модель KNN или мне нужно вызвать метод `best_params` grid_search'а, взять их и использовать в новом KNN классификаторе? Кто-нибудь может, пожалуйста, объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще полезно читать [документацию](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Смотрим, что там пишут про метод `predict`:

> Call predict on the estimator **with the best found parameters**.

Ну то есть можете просто вызвать `predict`, он отработает с теми самыми наилучшими найденными параметрами.

Comment: ясно, спасибо !